# Access Tomcat Variables from Play Framework

Tags: tomcat, playframework

I want to access the variable remoteUser that tomcat6 is getting (through mod_proxy_ajp) from Apache (mod_auth_kerb). Unfortunately its not sent as a RequestHeader Variable thats why I can't access it from the http.request object.

I activated valve-logging within Tomcat and it actually would log "remoteUser=user@PRINCIPLE.COM" whereas Host-Vars are like Header:Auth=Basic.

How do I access this "tomcat"-variable from play?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: BTW thats what I get from the Tomcat-Valve: http://pastebin.com/9dgCvKjh

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Tomcat intercepts all "REMOTE USER" headers.
There is a flag that can se to false to trigger this mechanism off in the server.xml

```
port="8009" minProcessors="5" maxProcessors="75"
acceptCount="10" debug="0" tomcatAuthenication="false"/>
```

As the authentication is not performed within Tomcat but within Apache in your architecture, it should be OK.

I'm not this is the solution...
Everything is explained longer here: http://www.tomcatexpert.com/knowledge-base/how-get-remote-user-attribute-tomcat

Comment: Tried that one already, still not getting the remote_user as a header but only as a session variable.

This is the output from the valve, as you can see I actually receive the Login-Name but not as a HTTP Header, but something Apache Specific.
http://pastebin.com/9dgCvKjh